# Asking for references on commutation and morita equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, morita-equivalence

I'm currently reading the chapter 8 of the book Algèbre of Bourbaki and I'm stuck on the sections 5 "Commutation" and 6 "Equivalence de Morita des modules et des algèbres".
At that point, I find this book very painful to read, the way they use to call other results from their book, the way that they wrote the book like just a succession of proposition and theorems and with very technical proofs, prevents me to develop an intuition and to understand clearly.

Does someone have another reference on these chapters which is readable please ?

Thank you